# How to get data object with Vue.js

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js

how to get **data on object with vue.js**
this my object data

```
schedules:Array[10]
 0:Object
   category:Object
    f_training_category_code:"NC" // this data
   expired:6
```

I want to take `f_training_category_code:"NC"`

i have tried with this

```
<tr v-for="schedule in schedules" :key="schedule.key">
  <td>@{{ schedule.category.f_training_category_code }}</td>      
</tr>
```

Comment: And what happened with that?

Comment: f_training_category_code undifined